# Incorrect results from custom sort function in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have created a sort function for sorting lists of integers, highest to lowest.
Here is the code:

```
def sort(list):
    s = []
    dropnum = 0
    l = len(list) - 1
    counter = 0
    s.append(list[0])
    while 1:
        maximum = len(s)
        if counter == l:
            break
        if list[counter] < s[dropnum]:
            dropnum = dropnum + 1
        else:
            counter = counter + 1
            if dropnum >= maximum:
                a.append(list[counter])
            else:
                s.insert(dropnum, list[counter])
            dropnum = 0
    return s
print sort([70,9,24,82,102])
```

I should get as output:

```
[102,82,70,24,9]
```

But I get:

```
[102, 82, 24, 9, 70]
```

Comment: Why not just use `reverse(sorted(list))`? Also, you shouldn't name your variables list since there's a builtin function called list. If this is homework please tag it as homework.

Comment: Why are you re-implementing `sorted()`? Is this homework?

Comment: Well, you do have `a.append()` instead of `s.append` after `if dropnum >= maximum:`. Also, it's generally a bad idea to use `list` as a variable name, as it's a built-in object in Python.

Comment: @agf: I think it's rude to tag something as homework unless you have reason to know that it's homework; and in this case, as far as I can see, you do not.

Comment: @ruakh I think the idea that this is anything _but_ homework is completely implausible. If we only tag things as homework where someone states that it's their homework, then all they have to do is _not say that_ and SO will do all their homework for them. I think anything that looks like homework should be tagged as such unless the person states it's not.

Comment: This algorithm is a little hard to follow. What's the purpose of `dropnum` and `counter`? Can you explain the algorithm or name it if it's one of the well-known ones? (It kinda sorta looks like insertsort, which isn't a great choice when using Python lists, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: `a.append()` wtf is `a`? Maybe that should be `s.append()`. Now do you see why all us old farts keep telling you to use meaningful variable names?

Comment: @agf I prefer to assume students asking for homework help have some integrity - and from my experience, they will in fact tag questions correctly when informed about the policy. I'd err towards at least giving new users the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @agf: You seem to have a number of strange ideas. Firstly: if it's *so obvious* that this is homework, then what are you worried about? Anyone who cares about not doing other people's homework will still care about that even if the homework isn't tagged. Secondly: believe it or not, some people do try to learn things -- even very elementary things -- even outside of school. Thirdly: it's more important to be respectful than to avoid giving homework help.

Comment: @ruakh He was free to remove the tag if it was incorrect, so I don't see it as disrespectful. I know people learn out of school, but they don't learn the same way that people learn in school. I can't imagine this question coming from anything but an assignment. I didn't say that it was obvious to everyone that this is homework, but it is obvious to me, which is why I re-tagged it.

Answer (score 1):

As I am sure you already know, python's builtin `sorted()` is a much more efficient way to sort.

```
print sorted([70,9,24,82,102], reverse=True)
```

Assuming this is a learning exercise, i think this is what you are trying to do

```
def sort(lst):
    s = []
    for item in lst:
        dropnum = 0
        while dropnum < len(s) and s[dropnum] > item:
            dropnum += 1
        s.insert(dropnum, item)
    return s
print sort([70,9,24,82,102])
```

You don't need that counter variable at all if you loop through the list the usual Python way

```
for item in lst:    # loop through the items in the input
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of easier options builtin to python:

```
list.sort(...)  # in-place, more memory efficient
```

and:

```
sorted(my_iterable, ...)  # returns a new copy
```

Both which optionally take a boolean `reverse` flag, custom `cmp` comparison function and `key` for defining what member to sort on

I believe both of these use a variation of quicksort implementation internally (for large collections, and a simpler iterative algo for smaller collections). for python versions 2.3+ the sort is guaranteed to be stable.

Futhermore, you should not name arguments or variables with the same name as builtin functions or types (e.g. `list`), since you pollute the namespace in the current scope.